# Text parsing looking for data with different strings expressing the base units (ex. square meters, sq.m, m^2, m2, etc.)

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing, text-processing

I'm trying to scrape the area number (square meters or square feet) of many residential properties which is stored in various txt files.

The area is almost always expressed by specifying the units, either in the metric system (length expressed with metre as base unit) or in the UK Imperial System (length expressed with foot as base unit) by giving a number followed by the units.

The area units have various string representations, for example "square meters" can appear as "sqm", "sq.m", "sq m", "square m", "sq.meters", "m^2", "m2", etc. (the capitalization of the different letters can also change).

Some Examples of the TXTs I have (I've copied only the line with the data I'm interested into, cleaning the rest):

1)

```
...
Approximate Gross Internal Area = 40.1 sq m / 432 sq ft Re’
...
```

2)

```
...
Total area: approx. 37.3 sq. metres (402.0 sq. feet)
...
```

3)

```
...
Approx. Gross Internal Area *
413Ft’-38.37M’
...
```

My goal is to parse each txt file, get the square metres (or square feet) number and store it.

I've started to look into Python Regular Expressions/RegEx, Pattern Matching, Text Processing and Text Parsing tools but I've decided to put the research on hold and see if anybody else ever had a similar goal.

What do you think is the most efficient way of solving this specific task? By using RegEx, Text Parsing or what?

I'm quite open to use other scripting languages (PERL, Ruby, etc.) if they're more suitable for this.

Comment: Your question is not clear: the only requirement that you're presenting is the need to either build a parser or use regex. Both can be done in most programing languages. Please focus your question!

Comment: There is too much unrelated information in this question. All mention of OCR and text files are completely redundant. You should shorten and rephrase your question to make it clear that you need to parse various string representations of area, and give some concrete examples on the variations. Sometimes regex works just fine, sometimes a parser is a better fit.

Comment: alfasin, that's part of what I'm asking for: is it better to use regex, a parser or something else?
Thanks anjdreas, I've edited as you've suggested (apart from making it shorter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Python RegEx code I've written to solve the issue, in case anybody will need it:

```
unit_pattern = re.compile(r"[+-]? *((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\s*(square meters|square metres|square meter|square metre|square m|square mt|sqmt|sq mt|sq.mt|sq. mt|sqm|sq m|sq.m|sq. m|meters2|metres2|meter2|metre2|mt2|m2)", re.IGNORECASE)
for i, line in enumerate(open('/Users/USERNAME/text.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(unit_pattern, line):
        print 'Found on line %s: %s' % (i+1, match.groups())
```

Applied on the following txt file:

```
eleventh Floor
Approx. 37.3 sq. metres (402.0 sq. feet)

Living
Room

7.06m x 4.04m
(23'2" x 13'3")

Bedroom
Area

Shower
Room

Total area: approx. 37.3 sq. metres (402.0 sq. feet)

For illustrative purposes only — Not to scale.
Plan produced using P|anUp.
```

Gives The following output:

```
Found on line 2: ('37.3', 'sq. m')
Found on line 16: ('37.3', 'sq. m')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to build a text parser that does database inserts (i suppose).

I think it's a simple task and can be implemented in all languages you suggested. There's no specific gain among them (except a matter of preference).

I suggest you adopt the language following this criteria:

1. Is the interpreter available at your production server?
2. Do you intend to nurse this code forever or do you intend someone else take care of it in a near future?

   - You

     - Choose the language you feel more comfortable with
   - Someone else

     - Choose a language that are easier to find workers in your area.

By the way, I would go for Python. It's easily available everywhere.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply.
To answer your questions:
1. My production server will be my laptop and R which is configurable with Python (and probably the other languages)
2. It's a personal project so I'll be the one taking care of it.
Same as you, I would prefer Python also because of the Scientific Computation toolboxes available in case I wanna replace R in toto for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a Perl interface to [Marpa](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), a general BNF parser.

The data can be described in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) as `this ::= that` (`~` operator defines lexical rules).

The parser returns a data structure (array of arrays in `[ id, child1, child2 ... ]` format), from which areas can be extracted.

You can also define [semantic actions](https://metacpan.org/source/JKEGL/Marpa-R2-3.000000/t/sl_action2.t#L51) as Perl `sub`'s in the same or separate package to process the data.

An example script and its output, based on your data, is below.

script:

```perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;

use Marpa::R2;

my $g = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),

    :default ::= action => [ name, value]
    lexeme default = action => [ name, value] latm => 1

    <area data>      ::= <area data item>+
    <area data item> ::= area
    <area>           ::= float unit

    float ~ int '.' int
    float ~ int '.'
    float ~ int
    int ~ [\d]+

    unit ~ 'sqm' | 'sq.m' | 'sq m' | 'square m' | 'sq.meters' | 'm^2' | 'm2'

    :discard ~ whitespace
    whitespace ~ [\s]+

END_OF_SOURCE
} );

my $input = <<EOI;
40.2 sq m
40 sqm
40. sq.m
40.2 sq m
40.2 square m
40.2 sq.meters
40.2 m^2
40.2 m2
EOI

say Dumper ${ $g->parse( \$input ) };
```

output:

```
[
  'area data',
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'sq m'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'sqm'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'sq.m'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'sq m'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'square m'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'sq.meters'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'm^2'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'area data item',
    [
      'area',
      [
        'float',
        '40.2'
      ],
      [
        'unit',
        'm2'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

There is nothing wrong with using regexes though. They are available in all languages you mention.

BNF can be more readable/maintainable, which is good when working with unstructured text.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply rns. I'll start with a regex and, in case that solution isn't sufficient to solve this task, I'll try another solution, BNF Parser included.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was requested by OP per email.

If you are able to use .NET libraries via IronPython or similar, then you might find use in [Units.NET](https://github.com/anjdreas/unitsnet) to parse your area strings. Or simply copy its parsing regex and modify to your needs.

Units.NET can parse value+unit string representations for most of the commonly used units, both metric and imperial.

Examples:

```
double a = Area.Parse("5 m²").SquareMeters; // 5.0
Area.Parse("0.092903m²").SquareFeet;        // ~1.0
Area.Parse("50000 cm²").ToString();         // "5 m²", sq.m is default unit
Area.Parse("1ft²").SquareMeters;            // 0.092903
Area.Parse("1 in²").SquareCentimeters;      // 6.4516
```

See [Area.json](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet/blob/master/UnitsNet/Scripts/UnitDefinitions/Area.json) for all area units and their abbreviations. Please note that SquareMeter currently only supports `"m²"`, but you can add more abbreviations like `"m^2"`, `"sq.m"`, `"sqm"` and so on at runtime via `UnitSystem.MapUnitToAbbreviation()` and we happily accept pull requests to add more unit abbreviations to the library. See [example](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet/blob/874bce9ecc1b5a8d6f95196367ef4b500ded798b/UnitsNet.Tests/UnitSystemTests.cs#L317).

Comment: Many thanks for the reply anjdreas. From your and other people answers I guess that a regex or a parser will be sufficient to solve this task, so I'll start by trying that solution first and see if it works before digging deeper with Units.NET.

Comment: Yes, regex is universally available in most languages. I'd start there and move to a parser if the regex becomes too unwieldy or slow. You can use [Units.NET's regex](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet/blob/master/UnitsNet/GeneratedCode/UnitClasses/Area.g.cs#L423) as a starting point for inspiration.